# Llamada Ajax devuelve código HTML en lugar de modelo serializado a JSON desde controlador Asp.Net Core

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-core

Algo muy extraño esta pasando cuando hago una llamada Ajax al controlador me está devolviendo código HTML(el de la pagina de login) en vez de devolverme un modelo que serializo como respuesta.

¿Qué puedo hacer para resolverlo?

Código JS

```
function PostUsuario() {

    var nombre = $('#nombre').val();
    var apellido = $('#apellido').val();
    var userName = $('#userName').val();
    var mail = $('#mail').val();
    var password = $('#password').val();
    var password2 = $('#password2').val();
    var rolId = 0;

    usuario = {

        Id: 0,
        Nombre: nombre,
        Apellido: apellido,
        UserName: userName,
        Email: mail,
        Password: password,
        RolId: 0,
    };

    $.ajax(
        {
            type: "POST",
            data: JSON.stringify(usuario),
            url: urlPostUsuario,
            cache: false,
            contentType: 'application/json',
            success: function (modelo) {
                console.log(modelo);
                if (modelo.estado) {
                    toastr.success(modelo.mensaje);
                    setTimeout(NavToLogin, 2000);
                }
                else {
                    toastr.error(modelo.mensaje);
                }
            }, error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                console.log(jqXHR + ' ' + textStatus + ' ' + errorThrown)
            }
        }
    );

    return false;
}
```

Código C#

```
 [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult UserRegister([FromBody] Usuario usuario)
    {
        var respuesta = new RespuestaModel();
        respuesta.Estado = false;

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(usuario.Nombre))
        {
            respuesta.Mensaje = "Mala solicitud";
            return Json(respuesta);
        }

        try
        {
            usuario = this._usuarioService.PostUsuario(usuario);
            if (usuario.Id > 0)
            {
                respuesta.Estado = true;
                respuesta.Mensaje = "Usuario creado correctamente.";
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            var logPath = this._webHostEnvironment.WebRootPath + AppEnviroments.log_excepcion;
            Helper.WriteFileLog(logPath, ex.Message);
            respuesta.Mensaje = ex.Message;
        }

        return Json(respuesta);
    }
```

Código HTML de respuesta

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>  Portal de Proveedores</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/site.css" asp-append-version="true" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/SiteDataProveedor.styles.css" asp-append-version="true" />
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <nav class="">
            <div class="container">
            
            </div>
        </nav>
    </header>
    <div class="container">
        <main role="main" class="pb-3">
            
    <script src="/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/js/scriptsSite/jsLogin/jsIndex.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
    <script src="/toaster/jquery.toaster.bootstrap.js"></script>
    <script src="/toaster/jquery.toast.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/toaster/toastr.min.css" />

<script>
    var urlLogin = '/Login/LoginUsuario';
    var urlHome = '/About';
    var urlUserRegister = '/Usuario';
</script>

<div class="card" style="margin-top:5%;">
    <div class="card-body">
        <div class="form-horizontal" style="color:dimgray">
            <h1 style="color:dimgray"> Acceso </h1>
            <small class="mb-md-0 text-gray" style="color:dimgray">Hola Comenzemos</small>
            <div class="form-group row">
                <div class="col-md-3 text-md-right">
                    <label class="control-label">Nombre de usuario</label>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-8">
                    <input type="text" id="userMail" name="userMail" class="form form-control" />
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3 text-md-right">
                    <label class="control-label">Password</label>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-8">
                    <input type="password" id="password" name="password" class="form form-control" />
                </div>

                <div class="col-md-3 text-md-right">
                    <label> Confirmar &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="checkbox" id="confirmar" class="form-check-input"></label><br>
                </div>

            </div>
            <div class="form-group row">
                <div class="col-md-3 text-md-right">
                    <label class="control-label">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</label>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-8">
                    <input type="button" value="Aceptar" class="btn btn-success form-control" onclick="Login();" />
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6 text-md-right" style="display:none;">
                    <input type="reset" value="Cancelar" class="btn btn-danger form-control" onclick="Reset()" style="width:200px;" />
                </div>
            </div>
            <div>
                <a href="" id="registrateAqui">Registrate Aqui</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

        </main>
    </div>

    <footer class="">
        <div class="container">
            &copy; 2023 - Portal de Proveedores <a asp-area="" asp-page=""> </a>
        </div>
    </footer>

    <script src="/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/lib/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/js/site.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>

    
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Será que como no estás logeado te redirige a la página de login sin ni siquiera entrar a ejecutar la acción del controlador.

Comment: ASP tiene páginas de errores, sobre todo en modo desarrollo. Cuando hay un error en tus datos de entrada, en la función  o en el login (como bien señala Jesús), te arroja una página con el informe de dicho error. Por eso no es extraño lo que señalas, para estar seguro pon un punto de interrupción en el `return` y comprueba que llega hasta ese punto, si no es así es que tienes un error previo

Comment: Gracias Jesus Lopez, Yussef sus comentarios fueron de gran ayuda

Answer (score 0):

Revisando dentro del proyecto me di cuenta que cuando se ejecutaban los filtros de la app , aunque podia llegar a la pagina de registrar un usuario, la accion como tal de registrar un usuario  no se habia validado para que se permitiera dentro del filtro.

Lo pude seleccionar de esta manera, retornando cuando la accion proviene del controlador usuario y validando sus respectivas acciones:

```
 public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
        {
            try
            {
                
                base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
                var action = filterContext.RouteData.Values.Values.ToList();
                if (action[0].ToString() == "Usuario" && (action[1].ToString() == "RegistroUsuario" || action[1].ToString() == "UserRegister"))
                  return;

                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(this.httpContext.HttpContext.Session.GetString("UsuarioLogin")))
                {
                    if (filterContext.Controller is LoginController == false )
                           filterContext.HttpContext.Response.Redirect("/Login/Index");
                }
            }
            catch
            {
                filterContext.Result = new RedirectResult("~/Login/Index");
            }
        }
```